# WCF database connection working but fails when accessing database from WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, wcf

I have a weird error occurring i've hit a brick wall with. I have my WCF service hosted on my web host, I can access this fine. I have a database set up on my web host and I have created the connection string to the database within my WCF web.config.

When I test the database connection to the database on the live server from my local WCF project the connection works fine. When I run my WPF application, it creates a contract with my WCF service (WPF app is local and WCF is live) I get the

> ERROR: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)"

I really don't understand how I can connect to the database from my local WCF project but not from my live one? Anyone got any tips on how to either resolve this or even how to identify where the issue is occurring?

Comment: Is there a code sample that you can provide that can help us help you?

Comment: Sorry Cameron I resolved it, see answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: Apologies for wasting your time but I had the database connection string hardcoded in a configuration file as well as in the web.config which is what was causing the problem. I meant to fix this before and forgot all about it.